# FirefoxをPythonのSeleniumで起動する時、proxyのusernameとpasswordを入力する方法

Tags: python3, ubuntu, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

FirefoxをPythonのSeleniumで起動する際、下の画像の様にproxyのusernameとpasswordの入力を要求されますが、
こちらをpythonのscriptから入力する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私の実行環境

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Python 3.9.1
selenium 3.141.0 py39h07f9747_1002 conda-forge
geckodriver 0.29.0 (2021-01-14, cf6956a5ec8e)
```

私が実行したpythonのスクリプトは下記の通りです。

```py
# proxyのユーザー名とパスワード
USERNAME = "suzuki"
PASSWORD = "hoge"

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'~/path_to_driver/geckodriver')
sleep(5)

# 下記2行でブラウザー立ち上げ後に、USERNAMEとTABキーとPASSWORDを入力し、OKボタンを押させているつもりですが、全く反応しません
browser.switch_to.alert.send_keys(USERNAME + u'\ue004' + PASSWORD) 
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

上記のコードを実行すると、FIrefoxのブラウザは立ち上がってProxyのユーザー名とパスワードを要求されますが、何も入力されません。ターミナル上には下記のエラーメッセージが出力されます。
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException message`
Proxy入力のポップアップがアラートとして認識されていないということでしょうか。

最後の2行は下記の回答を参考に作りました。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220686/10432875

タブの入力方法(u'\ue004')は
https://qiita.com/KI1208/items/effe553d1ce9a9d04d76
を参考にしました。

ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

試す環境が無いのでキーワードで調べただけですが、英語版SOでの類似質問における回答の一つで、
以下のような方法が紹介されていました。

[Using a http proxy with headless firefox in Selenium webdriver in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514532)

> ```py
> from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
>
> myProxy = "username:password@proxyDomain:proxyPort"
>
> proxy = Proxy({
>     'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
>     'httpProxy': myProxy,
>     'ftpProxy': myProxy,
>     'sslProxy': myProxy,
>     'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
>     })
>
> driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, proxy=proxy)
> ```

Comment: cubick◆ 様　わざわざ調べていただきありがとうございます。その質問を読んで、試してみたのですが、やはりうまくいかなかったです。`Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: The proxy moz-proxy://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX is requesting a username and password. The site says: "Squid proxy-caching web server"`というエラーメッセージを吐きました